# Proving sequence is bounded below?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I have the function: 
$$
a_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\ldots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{n}
$$

How could I go about proving that this sequence is bounded from below? When plotting it, I can see it converges to around -1.45, but I can't figure out how to try and prove it's bounded arithmetically. I was trying to figure out how to manipulate it to use the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality, but had no such luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}= \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{k}} \ge \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}= 2\sqrt{k+1}- 2\sqrt{k}$, and take the sum for $k$ runs from $1$ to $n-1$.

Comment: Thank you! I got it from here :) for some reason I couldn't figure out the appropriate inequality to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the graph of $y=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$, it’s clear that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\ge\int_1^{n+1}x^{-1/2}\,dx=2\left[\sqrt{x}\right]_1^{n+1}=2\sqrt{n+1}-2$$

and hence that

$$a_n\ge 2\sqrt{n+1}-2-2\sqrt{n}=2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)-2>-2\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that
$$ a_{n+1}-a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})}<0 $$
hence the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is decreasing and
$$a_N-a_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(a_{n+1}-a_n) = -\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2} $$
so that
$$ a_N \geq a_1-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2} $$
where the last series is clearly convergent, since its general term behaves like $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$.
 You may also check that
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})^2}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n-\frac{1}{6}}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+\frac{5}{6}}} $$
from which
$$ a_N \geq \color{red}{-1-\sqrt{\frac{3}{10}}} $$
follows by creative telescoping.

Answer (score -1):

If
$a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{k}}-2\sqrt{n}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
d(n)
&=a_{n+1}-a_n\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\\
&<\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&=0\\
\text{and}\\
d(n)
&>\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-2\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})}\\
&>\dfrac{-1}{2n\sqrt{n}}\\
\text{so}\\
a_{n+k}-a_n
&=\sum_{j=1}^k (a(n+j)-a(n+j-1))\\
&< 0\\
\text{and}\\
a_{n+k}-a_n
&=\sum_{j=1}^k (a(n+j)-a(n+j-1))\\
&>\sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac{-1}{2(n+j-1)\sqrt{n+j-1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$a_n$ is a decreasing sequence
which is bounded below
since
$\sum \dfrac1{n^{3/2}}
$
converges.

For an explicit bound,
since
$\dfrac1{x^{3/2}}
$
is decreasing for
$x \ge 1$,
$\dfrac1{x^{3/2}}
\lt \int_{x-1}^x \dfrac{dt}{t^{3/2}}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac{1}{(n+j-1)\sqrt{n+j-1}}
&\lt\sum_{j=1}^k \int_{n+j-2}^{n+j-1} \dfrac{dt}{t^{3/2}}\\
&\lt\int_{n-1}^{n+k-1} \dfrac{dt}{t^{3/2}}\\
&\lt\int_{n-1}^{\infty} \dfrac{dt}{t^{3/2}}\\
&\lt\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n-1}}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+k}-a_n
&>\sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac{-1}{2(n+j-1)\sqrt{n+j-1}}\\
&\gt\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\\
\text{or}\\
a_{n+k}
&>a_n-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\\
\end{array}
$

As is often the case,
nothing here is original
and I worked it out
as I went along.